# Disable all out of the box emails in approval workflow

Tags: workflow, email

I used sharepoint out of the box approval workflow, and it sends the basic out of the box email to users. I tried setting it in the task list by going to advanced settings and disabling the emails, but the workflow is applied on the library, and sends an email once the approval process is started.

I tried to go to sharepoint designer to edit the workflow, but the workflow isn't showing there. Instead, there are MANY workflows there in many languages, but my out of the box workflow i created isn't showing there to edit.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of The `Globally reusable approval workflow` is **read-only** so you can't change its behavior till get a copy from it .

So take a copy and change the **Send Email** actions based on your requirement by doing the following.

- Right click on Approval workflow > Copy and Modify.

[image]

- Select the content type to `All` or `item` if it's related to item in your list.
- Click on the copied workflow > click on Edit workflow.
- Click on `Start Approval workflow Task`.

[image]

- At `customization section` > Click on

  - change the behavior of a single task.
  - change the behavior of overall task.

[image]

- Here you can find `Send Email action` that you can delete it based on your requirement.

[image]

- Or customize it as you want by clicking on `current task : Assigned to`.
- Publish your workflow , assign it to your list at `workflow settings` at the list/library ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jacky , are you still face any issue to disable emails ? your feedback is very important for all users so please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification for the above answer :)